# How to show a Default Message if Cross Tab contains no data

Tags: birt

I am very new to Birt Tool

If Data cube contains no data, I am able to  hide Cross tab, but my problem is i am unable to show default Message like  "No Records Found"

please give me some suggestion on it.

Advanced Thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

Add a new table to the report under the crosstab, bound to the same datasource as the crosstab, and add your desired message ("No Records Found") as a Text item to the report footing. Set the Visibility property of the Text item to be hidden for all outputs, conditional on the expression:

```
row.__rownum > 0
```

Ensure that your new table has the same filters set up as the crosstab.

Comment: hi  mark,  it is working but in one of my report is not working,  there i have used one computed columns in data set

Comment: @venkat: Are you filtering on that computed column in that report?